# how to goto a specific line in eclipse while developing a eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin and i display certain line numbers in a view. when user clicks the line number i want the focus to be gone to that line number of particular file in the main editor. How this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the current line in the active text editor using something like this:

```java
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IEditorPart editorPart = page.getActiveEditor();

if (editorPart instanceof ITextEditor) {
   ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor)editorPart;

   IDocumentProvider provider = editor.getDocumentProvider();
   IDocument document = provider.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());

   try {
     int lineStart = document.getLineOffset(line);
     editor.selectAndReveal(lineStart, 0);

     page.activate(editor);
   } catch (BadLocationException x) {
        // ignore
   }
}
```

(based on the code from the 'Goto Line' dialog)